# Memory Management and static CoreFoundation variables

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, static, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

First of all, I'm using ARC.

If I have a class that, for example, looks like this:

```
static CFNumberRef numberRef = NULL;

+ (void)initialize {
    float myFloat = 28.37202;
    numberRef = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFNumberFloatType, &myFloat);
}
```

How would I go about releasing `numberRef`?

Comment: This looks like a singleton. So treat it as a singleton: don't release it at all. The kernel will clean up all the memory when your app exits.

Comment: @H2CO3 I suppose that would be the right answer and right enough, there's no leaks that I can see.

Comment: I made that an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pattern you're using resembles the way singletons are created and managed, I'd say you can treat your object as an actual singleton. This means that you don't need to release it. (Think a bit about it - personally, I have never seen a singleton implementation in Objective-C/Cocoa that would have cared about releasing the shared instance). This behavior is in accordance with the fact that you need the object to be alive throughout the lifetime of your application. So don't release it at all - when the process terminates, the kernel will make sure to clean up all the resources it acquired.

Answer (score 1):

Release it somewhere that you know you won't need it anymore. I'm assuming it's static because you have many of these classes and always need this memory? I'd suggest in `applicationWillTerminate`. If you don't have many classes and don't always need the memory, then maybe declaring it as static isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm using it in a `UITableViewCell` case where `drawRect` is called many times per second. How would you release it in `applicationWillTerminate:` outside of AppDelegate?

Comment: It sounds like you need a const, not a static.

Comment: @BoA: Many application delegate methods correspond to notifications. That's one of them; it's [UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification).

Answer (score 0):

All coreFoundation are by default `assign`-ed, so it is never retained, therefore no need of releasing.

To be clear, ARC has no effect whatsoever on Core Foundation objects. It doesn't attempt to automatically manage them, so you need to [manually manage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) them.

If you create memory of your own by `calloc/malloc`, then you need to `free` them.

EDIT :

Q: I just want to understand this clearly... even with ARC, we still have to worry about doing CFRelease() and also other types of releases such as CGContextRelease(context);

Ans: Correct. ARC only handles ObjC objects. It doesn't know anything about Core Foundation objects.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear but I'm talking about ones where you have to `CFRelease`.